# How to fix the SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

Hi When I use the following code I get the following error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame  See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy   df['sic_code'][index] = comp_dict[key]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for key in comp_dict:
        if row['code'] == key:
            df['sic_code'][index] = comp_dict[key]
```

I have tried using the code below  which does remove the error but it changes the output of the code so that the changes I want do not occur. To show you what I mean when I use the below code I get [image] which Is wrong when i use the above code (which produces the error) I get [image].

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for key in comp_dict:
        if row['code'] == key:
            df.loc[df['sic_code'][index]] = comp_dict[key]
```

Comment: Try `df.loc[index, 'sic_code']`. You want to avoid `][` when you are setting values.

Comment: the fourth question in the [`frequent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas?tab=Frequent) tab for pandas is the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas?tab=Frequent) , my genuine advice is to read the frequent tab when starting on a particular tag

Comment: @anky is right, this has been addressed before, however looping over rows is costly, try `df.row = df.row.replace(key, comp_dict[key])` within the second loop

Comment: thanks for the help, to be fair I always google a fair bit before asking for help mostly because its obviously quicker than waiting for an answer - that said I will endever to check next time.

Comment: regarding df.row = df.row.replace(key, comp_dict[key]) i got the error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'row'